# What's the doorbell in InfiniBand?

Tags: infiniband, rdma

I am reading a document ablut InfiniBand, which is called 《[InfiniBand™ Host Channel Adapter Verb Implementer’s Guide](http://gg.qwghq.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwj5pYTRtq7PAhXHGZQKHfSODpcQFggeMAA&url=%68%74%74%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%66%69%6E%69%62%61%6E%64%2E%73%6F%75%72%63%65%66%6F%72%67%65%2E%6E%65%74%2F%48%57%44%72%69%76%65%72%73%2F%48%43%41%5F%44%44%4B%2F%56%49%47%5F%53%46%2E%70%64%66&usg=AFQjCNEbpysn29AOR16rHbhFiYHl_qtfUA)》--Intel, in Chapter 6.2.2, it mentions a concept called "Doorbell", I haven't found any information about this concept in the IB specification. I wonder if the doorbell is a notification mechnism or something else? Is there something detail about it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The definition is two sections further up under 6.2:

> Protection domain is used as a form of access security for memory regions, address vectors and queue pairs as defined by the InfiniBand Architecture. The Architecture requires a protection domain before a QP is allocated. Most vendors who expect to support user mode IO, will have a form of notification handshake from user mode. In most HCA’s this is a device memory address mapped to the process address space. We call this address the “doorbell” in this document.

CTRL-F is your friend...